# android studio - How to make two custom application classes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-productflavors, leakcanary

I'd like to design two custom applications for my android project. A custom application is one that extends application.  I'd like my release build to have a custom application and the debug build to have another one.  LeakCanary site talks about this [here](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) in the section labeled "*Customizing and using the no-op dependency*".

I cant seem to figure out how i would declare another application in the androidManifest.  Right now i have it set to use a single custom application like this:

```
public class MyFirstCustomApplication extends Application {

@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LeakCanary.install(this);
}
}
```

How do i make the above code for debug only ?

and the androidManifest override looks like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="org.somesite.cool.MyFirstCustomApplication">
```

How would i have another MySecondCustomApplication for release ?

UPDATE: on the suggestions of looking into bulidTypes in gradle imagine i did the following structure for my debug application override:

```
[Project Root]
  -[Module]
    -src
      -main
        -ExampleApplication 
        -res

      -debug
        -DebugExampleApplication
        -res
```

so if i understand buildTypes correctly then if i only have a main folder its used for both release and debug (its the default/fall back) but if i specify a debug folder then if i run any debug flavors i might have like mockDebug,qaDebug, etc then it will first look in the debug folder for the file and then go to main if not found, is that correct ?

Also, then how would i declare in my manifest which one to use ? What would the gradle file look like ?

Comment: you can put release and debug specific code in their own directory. You can declare the same application class for both, and have a different behavior in the respective files

Comment: You'll need to make use of [Build types](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts).

Comment: if thats the case how did the leakcanary site use different names for the custom application override? they used ExampleApplication and Debug ExampleApplication ? but the androidManifest can only have one application delcared in it? are you saying i can also make two androidManifests one in debut and one in main. I'll update my question with what i found so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cant seem to figure out how i would declare another application in the androidManifest.

You only have one in the manifest.

> so if i understand buildTypes correctly then if i only have a main folder its used for both release and debug (its the default/fall back) but if i specify a debug folder then if i run any debug flavors i might have like mockDebug,qaDebug, etc then it will first look in the debug folder for the file and then go to main if not found, is that correct ?

Assuming that `mockDebug` is a `mock` flavor and a `debug` build type (and likewise for `qaDebug`), then yes.

So, you have your `Application` class in the same Java package in the `debug` and `release` build types. The manifest, and the Java code using your `Application` class, will refer to it in that one Java package. Which edition of your `Application` class you get will depend on whether you are doing a `debug` build or a `release` build.

> Also, then how would i declare in my manifest which one to use ?

The same as normal.

> What would the gradle file look like ?

No changes are needed for any Gradle build files for this.

> on the suggestions of looking into bulidTypes in gradle imagine i did the following structure for my debug application override

No, at least as how I would view the project tree. You would have:

```
[Project Root]
  -[Module]
    -src
      -main
        -java
          - your.package.here
            - Things.java
            - ThatAre.java
            - NotYourCustomApplication.java
            - ButOtherwiseAreCommon.java
            - ForAllBuildTypes.java
        -res

      -debug
        -java
          - your.package.here
            - YourCustomApplication.java
        -res

      -release
        -java
          - your.package.here
            - YourCustomApplication.java
        -res
```

Note that it is the same `your.package.here` and the same `YourCustomApplication.java` in each of the build type-specific sourcesets.

Comment: Good answer. I guess the thing that threw me off track was on leakcanary they were using different names for the classes: DebugExampleApplication and ExampleApplication.  I tried with manifestPlaceholders but it would not be able to replace the name for application, other strings worked though.  IN the end your solutions works.

Comment: with kotlin the files cannot be named the same.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to use two different classes, you can always take advantage of the manifest merger. In the debug folder, add your second application class and a manifest containing only the new app name

```
<manifest package="your.package"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application
        android:name=".DebugExampleApplication"
        tools:replace="android:name"/>
</manifest>
```